# Populating a Combo Box

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, datasource, local-database

I created a `Windows Form`, with a `ComboBox`, and a `Local Database` in Visual Studio 2010. The database has a table with a column whose rows I want to list in the combo box. How can I achieve this?

I tried adding a `data source` with the column I am interested in through the IDE, but it did not work.

---

I created a `Windows Forms Application` with a `Windows Form` containing a `ComboBox`.

[image]

I created a `Local Database` containing a `Table` with a single column and three test rows.

[image]

I added a `data source` containing the column I am interested in.

[image]

Finally, I bound the combo box to the data source, but the result is strange.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you have written thus far.  We aren't psychics here; just fellow nerds.

Comment: @Brian, I fixed the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the raw code to accomplish what you are asking:

```
string strCmd = "";
string strConn = "";
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, sqlConn);
SqlDataReader sqlRdr = new SqlDataReader();

sqlConn.Open();

if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
   comboBox1.Items.Clear();
sqlRdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlRdr.Read())
   comboBox1.Items.Add(sqlRdr[0].ToString());

sqlRdr.Close();
sqlConn.Close();
```

There are a few things you will need to wire-up first though.  The first one is this:

```
string strCmd = "";  // Insert your SQL statement here.
```

Second:

```
string strConn = "";  // Your db connection string goes here.
```

Thirdly:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)  // You don't have to use this. It just checks to see 
   comboBox1.Items.Clear();     // if there is anything in the combobox and clears it.
```

Lastly, since you are making something that handles interactions between your form and a database, I *strongly* suggest that you use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.